# is it possible to create a popup contact form from a product button

Tags: javascript, product-view, popup, contact-form

How would I go about creating a simple popup from a 'view.phtml' on a product page that would popup 'form.phtml' from template/contacts.

I am trying to create a free quote button on a product page, so I would like the the form to have the basic contact form, but also have the submit email the address link that the user was left off on, or the product image.

Is this easily done? or is there a paid solution somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: you need the contact form in popup and need to send email right?

Comment: @saravanavelu yes this would be what im looking for.

Comment: Try the jQuery fancy box plugin for popup

Comment: is that not for images only?

Comment: with that you can load the content also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom module but it does not take much work if you know some basics of module development:

1. create a controller action that does nothing more than

   ```
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->renderLayout();
   ```
2. Create a layout handle for this controller and include the predefined `page_empty` layout handle (this removes header, footer and sidebars, using `page/empty.html` as root template). Also add the contact form block via layout:

   ```
   <layout>
       <your_controller_action>
           <update handle="page_empty"/>
           <reference name="content">
               <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
           </reference>
       </your_controller_action>
   </layout>
   ```
3. if you want to prefill the contact form text area, you'll have to use an adjusted `contacts/form.phtml` which takes a parameter for the default value of the text area. Copy `contacts/form.phtml` to sth. like `mycontact/form.phtml` (change the template path in the layout XML accordingly), and change this line

   ```
   <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMessage()) ?></textarea>
   ```

   Then add this line to your controller action:

   ```
   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setMessage(
       $this->getRequest()->getParam('message'));
   ```
4. Finally, create a link to open the popup in your `product/view.phtml`:

   ```
   <?php
   $popupMessage = "This message will be prefilled in the popup contact form.\n";
   $popupMessage.= "You can add the product URL or anything else here:\n";
   $popupMessage.= $this->getProduct()->getUrl();
   ?>
   <a href="javascript:popWin('<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->getUrl('your/controller/action', array('message' => $popupMessage)))); ?>', 'contact')">Popup</a>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create pop yourself .I will give you how to call contacts us form at product view page by below code

```
<?php   $this->getLayout()->getCreateBlock('catalog/product_view')
->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('cotacts/index/post') )->setTemplate('contacts/productform.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Here I create a template file `productform.phtml` which is replicate of default `contacts>form.phtml file.`